# Is a User logged in

Tags: apex, user-management

I need to build some logic that assigns leads to Reps that are currently logged in.
How can I find with APEX if a user is currently logged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom line is that you can't do this in a reliable way using Apex - we've had a few tries at it.  The best we've been able to come up with is a sidebar component that updates a custom field on the user or a related custom object whenever it is rendered.  However, given the web nature of the Salesforce UI, you only know what the user is doing when they choose to interact with a page, so if they close the browser immediately after opening that page you have no way of knowing it.

You could use the mechanism I've outlined above to figure out reps who were recently seen on the system, then assign them the lead, but add some time based workflow that takes action if the lead doesn't get updated inside a period of time - kind of like case escalation. It will still be rather hit and miss though.

Answer (score 11):

**Platform Change** : [As of v29.0](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm#sforce_api_objects_authsession) you can now query the `AuthSession` object .
 According to the [session timeout documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/securityImplGuide/Content/admin_sessions.htm), the last `LastModifiedDate` on the `AuthSession` gets updated when there is activity by the user in the last half of his or her the session.

**An approach** making use of the above : If you are prepared to reduce the session timeout to `15` minutes (the minimum value permitted) , you can arrive at a fairly viable solution that's accurate to within at least `15` minutes or even better if the last activity by a user was within `7.5` minutes of their respective session expiring.

Again its worth repeating the advice in earlier answers - no approach will  be 100% accurate

**Heres an experiment** I performed at `15:15` which appears to validate the salesforce documentation links above -  I initiated a `standard UI session` and a `workbench session` straight after.

Under workbench I ran the following query

```
[ 
  SELECT   LastModifiedDate,LoginType,NumSecondsValid,SessionType,UsersId
  FROM AuthSession 
  WHERE SessionType = 'UI'
        AND LoginType = 'Application'
]
```

at `15:20` the query returned

`AuthSession:{ ... LastModifiedDate=2014-01-26 15:15:12, ...}`

At `15:23`

- I navigated  to a detail view of an `Account`
- I then ran the same query under workbench which returned

`AuthSession:{... LastModifiedDate=2014-01-26 15:22:16, ...}`

**Summary**

The basic approach for the *"approximate reps logged in table"* is therefore as follows:

- Set the `session timeout` to the  minimum available ( 15 minutes ).
- Create a SOQL query over the `AuthSession` object
  filtering on `SessionType = 'UI'  AND LoginType = 'Application'` returning `userIds`
- Although Salesforce appears to eliminate expired session records, consider dropping any records `WHERE System.Now() >       authSession.LastModifiedDate.AddSeconds(authSession.NumSecondsValid)`
- Finally filter this  list of `UserIds` to only those Ids representing Reps

Answer (score 1):

Try the LoginHistory API: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm 
 But I'm not sure you'll have much milage there.

Would you be open to a different solution?

I can see one where you assign the reps to a queue when a lead is created, and notify them by email. if the lead doesn't have an owner after a couple of hours, send out another email, and so on

Create a report/dashboard to see the leads without owners that have been open the longest, and a report on people with leads that meets some criteria .

It's not what you asked for, but an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for same, got in to this app, check it out. 
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wXa0EAE