# How to update the User obj when the Session expiry time changes

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger AvailabilityStatusUpdate on User (before Update) {    
    DateTime lastModifiedDate;
    Integer noOfSecondsValid;

    for( User userObj : Trigger.New) {           
        LIST<AuthSession> session = [ SELECT LastModifiedDate, NumSecondsValid
                                     FROM AuthSession WHERE UsersId = : userObj.Id] ;    

        for(AuthSession sessionObj : session) {
            noOfSecondsValid = sessionObj.NumSecondsValid;
            lastModifiedDate = sessionObj.LastModifiedDate;
        }
        userObj.SessionExpiryTime__c = lastModifiedDate.addSeconds( noOfSecondsValid ); 

        if( userObj.SessionExpiryTime__c > System.now())
            userObj.AvailabilityStatus__c = 'Available';

        List<AggregateResult> loginHistoryObj = [SELECT MAX(LoginTime) FROM LoginHistory 
                                                 WHERE UserId = : userObj.Id GROUP BY UserId];

        DateTime loginDateTime = (DateTime)loginHistoryObj[0].get('expr0');
        Date loginDate = loginDatetime.date();
        if( logindate != (userObj.TimeNow__c).date())
            userObj.AvailabilityStatus__c = 'Absent';
    } 
}
```

I have used the above given piece of code to write a trigger. However, I want it to fire and update the USer Obj as and when the Session expiry Time changes. I am unable to fire it.

Firing the given query I get AvailabilityStatus and SessionExpiryTime blank.

```
SELECT username, id, AvailabilityStatus__c,CaseCounter__c, TimeNow__c, SessionExpiryTime__c from user
```

Please suggest.

Comment: A trigger only runs when a change to an object is made: what change to the `User` object are you expecting to cause your trigger to run? Also the `AuthSession` object seems to contain only live sessions which may break your logic. I recommend you add debug statements to see what is going on - e.g. to see if the trigger ever fires and if it does whether  `AuthSession` ever has any rows. See e.g. [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code).

Comment: I have added a Formula field as well as a normal DateTime field with default value of now() so that an update of time fires up every second. But I have come to know that a Formula field cannot fire a trigger( Probably, because these are run time calculations and not the SML operations).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10995/is-a-user-logged-in

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Please check the content before marking a duplicate. Heading same may not mean the same question.

Comment: @user2703132 I agree with you, I have updated the subject to reflect the question which is in turn different to the marked duplicate.