# Custom Functionality on user click of Activation Link

Tags: user, user-management

We are using OOTB functionality to send Activation Email to both portal users and salesforce users.

As this is OOTB functionality, salesforce acts the same way irrespective of the user type when user clicks on the activation link.

Requirement is to do different functionality based on the user type. For example, if the a portal user clicks on the activation link then there should be different functionality when compared to the standard salesforce user clicking on the activation link.

Is there any way to customize salesforce to behave differently based on the user type when the activation link is clicked?

Comment: another way of framing this question would be "can I get control when a user activates their seat" - for example by a trigger on User; some related stuff here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10995/2602 - `AuthSession`s seem to be ephemeral

Comment: Not exactly, we are not looking at controlling the user activities. The actual requirement is for the activation link to perform different actions. For example, if the activation link is expired the user would be redirected to salesforce login page with an error messag. We need salesforce to behave differently here. If the user is portal user, then  we should show different message telling user that the activation link has expired, and ask him to contact customer care. Where as if the user is internal user, then the standard functionality should be followed.